# How to get object and many to many object information

Tags: python, django

I want to get information: if request user vote for this project.

My Project class:

```
class Project(TimestampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    votes = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

My query, I tried get it by annotate and filter inside, but not work

```
  queryset = Project.objects.all()
        if 'title' in filters.keys() and filters['title'] is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(title__icontains=filters['title'])
        queryset = queryset.annotate(num_votes=Count("votes"))
        queryset = queryset.annotate(user_vote=Count("votes__user_id", filter=Q(votes__user_id=filters['user_id'])))
        queryset = queryset.order_by('-created_at')
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.

queryset = queryset.annotate(user_vote=Count("votes__user_id", filter=Q(votes__id=filters['user_id'])))

I didn't know that votes__id is equivalent to user id in this relation

Answer (score 0):

Try to use related name on a votes field:

`votes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='projects')`
That way you can access all projects that user voted for by this `related_name`

```
user = User.objects.filter(username='john')
user.projects.all() # > all projects that user voted for
```